# Rake - failing builds for warnings

Tags: rake

I am trying to automate our build system and one of the task is to fail the builds if a warnings is thrown in the compiler.

we are using sh rake command to compile.

How one can fail on warnings, is there any way i can capture the output from compiler to a buffer and do a pattern search?

Thanks,
Prabhu

Comment: Does the build fail for compiler errors?  Can the compiler be set to throw errors instead of warnings? (i.e. does the compiler have a strict mode?)

Comment: Hi Robert,

We are trying to compile for different targets with each having its own compiler. Some do support these others do not. I am not able to do this for ARM Compiler.

Thanks,
Prabhu

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumbles on this question and is wondering the same thing you want to look into something like the ruby module [Open3](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html).

This "grants you access to stdin, stdout, stderr" and as such would allow you to detect when a build fails... for instance:

```
def runcommand(cmdLine)
  stdout, stderr, status = Open3.capture3(cmdLine)
  fail "Build Failed\n#{stderr}" unless status.success?
end
```